# How to create an RDF resource for each item of combo box?

Tags: java, rdf, jena

I have this frame :  
[image: myframe]

The button "add" allows to add dynamically combo boxes,this is its code :

```
add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                c4 = new JComboBox();
                req1();
                panel_2.add(c4);
                panel_2.revalidate();
            }
```

I want to create an RDF resource for  each item of the combo boxes that I add dynamically to my frame , but the problem is : when I add for example 2 combo boxes only one RDF resource will be created.
This the code of the button "generate RDF ":

```
    btnGenerateRdf.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                String u = c2.getSelectedItem().toString();//item of the first combo box
                String un = c4.getSelectedItem().toString();// item of the combo box that will be added dynamically
                Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    
                String u1 = u.substring(u.lastIndexOf("#") + 1);//to get the name from the URI 
                String str=u1.replace('_',' ');
                String un2=un.substring(un.lastIndexOf("#") + 1);
                String str1=un2.replace('_',' ');
                
                
    Resource node = model.createResource(u) .addProperty(FOAF.name, str);//resource of the the first combo box
           Resource[] r = new Resource[panel_2.getComponentCount()];    
         for(int i=0 ;i<panel_2.getComponentCount();i++)    
            { 
            r[i]= model.createResource(un).addProperty(FOAF.name, str1);
             }
       
          try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\nasro\\Desktop\\file.xml");
                model.write(out,"RDF/XML");
                out.close();
                
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          
          
            }
        });
```

Anyone can help me please ?

Comment: I cannot follow you. you create one RDF triple for `u` and one for `un`. What is missing in the end? If `u` and `un` are the same, you will see only one RDF triple in the file.

Comment: @UninformedUser `u` and  `un` are not the same ,`un` is the item of the combo box `c4` that will be added dynamically by clicking on the "add" button , I want to create for each combo box `c4` a triple .

Comment: I know that both are not the same. But I don't understand what is not working. In your code you have exactly 2 comboboxes and for each you get the selected item and at a triple with it's `foaf:name` for it. So what exactly does not work here?

Comment: what I also don't get is the purpose of this loop `for(int i=0 ;i<panel_2.getComponentCount();i++)  ` ? what is it supposed to do? You are always creating the same resource with the same triple, that doesn't make sense

Comment: @UninformedUser  the "add"  button  allows to add dynamically a combo box to my frame whenever I click on it ,and that combo box is named `c4`, for example if I click 4 times, 4 combo boxes will be added ,I want to create for each of them a triple , and my code only works for one.

Comment: but don't you see that you hard-coded it for exactly two comboboxes? I mean, you `for`-loop is useless because you do not use the component in it. You just add exactly the same triple `n` time with `n` being the number of components on your panel. You have to iterate over all comboboxes on your panel then. And for each such combobox you have to get the selected element and add the triple.

Comment: Yes,but I don't know how to do this ,Can you give me please an example of code of  how to iterate all the combo boxes  ?

Comment: `panel_2.getComponents()` will give you all components on your panel. Obviously, you have to filter by the type of it, i.e. `instanceof` operator in Java. The rest is straightforward

Comment: Thank you so much for your help , I fixed my code and it works now.

Comment: @UninformedUser Can you help me please  in this question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63012915/how-to-iterate-through-dynamically-added-combo-boxes-in-jpanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63012915/how-to-iterate-through-dynamically-added-combo-boxes-in-jpanel)? this time I need to add 3 combo boxes to my panel .